# Why do I need to run `ssh-add` in my Powershell profile?

Tags: powershell, posh-git

In my **Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1** document, I've had to add `ssh-add ~/.ssh/github_rsa` following the poshgit examples in order for it to connect to my GitHub repos.

```
# Load posh-git example profile
. 'C:\tools\poshgit\dahlbyk-posh-git-8aecd99\profile.example.ps1'

ssh-add ~/.ssh/github_rsa
```

If I don't have that in my profile, I Github gives me permissions errors when I try to connect.

If I do it manually, it will work for the entire duration of my desktop session, but as soon as I reboot my computer, I need to re-run the command.

Why doesn't poshgit and ssh-add remember the rsa that I've added? It seems wrong to have to re-add it every time.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's because your rsa key is not the default name ( id_rsa ) so you either need to use ssh-add (which adds it to a running service that remembers the key decrypted with your passphrase) or just add an entry into your `~\.shh\config`

`~\.ssh\config` (create or edit):

```
Host github.com
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github_rsa
```

Or, if github is the only thing you use ssh keys for, just rename the key to id_rsa and then git (well ssh.exe) will find it for you automatically AND poshgit will ssh-add it for you (to handle passphrases).

Comment: ah, that makes perfect sense. It's not my only key since I use two different instances of GitBlit for my business purposes as well.

Comment: Works great. I also renamed `github_rsa` to `id_rsa_github` because for some reason, the other way wouldn't work...

Comment: @Chase Florell did you mean rename it to id_rsa

Comment: @tofutim, no... doing that would make it the default.

Comment: my posh-git doesn't seem to read the config file - did you do something different than the default?

Comment: Another line one could add is "Preferredauthentications publickey" making sure the key is really used.